# Indexing by column name to the end of the dataframe - R

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing

I'm wondering if there is a way to select a group of columns by the name of the first column in the group and then all the next columns either a) to the end of the data frame, or b) to another column, also using its name.

a) As an example for the first question, in the `mtcars` dataset, is there a way to select the columns from `drat` to the end of the data frame? (Something like `mtcars[,'drat':ncol(mtcars)]`)

b) For the second question, is there a way to select the columns starting at `cyl` and ending at `wt`? (Something like `mtcars[,'cyl':'wt']`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do with this with `select` from `dplyr`

Answer a)

```
mtcars %>% select(drat:get(last(names(.))))
```

Answer b)

```
mtcars %>% select(cyl:wt)
```

Answer (score 3):

Many elegant solutions already provided but one can even use `base-R` to get the desired result using `which` as:

**Ans a:**

```
mtcars[,which(names(mtcars) == "drat"):ncol(mtcars)]
```

**Ans b:**

```
mtcars[,which(names(mtcars) == "cyl"):which(names(mtcars) == "wt")]
#                    cyl  disp  hp drat    wt
#Mazda RX4             6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620
#Mazda RX4 Wag         6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875
#Datsun 710            4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320
#Hornet 4 Drive        6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215
#Hornet Sportabout     8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440
#......so on
```

Answer (score 1):

In `dplyr`, the `select` function does exactly this (no quotes needed):

```
mtcards %>%
  select(cyl:wt)
```

Answer (score 1):

If we need to use a quoted string, convert it to `sym` (`symbol`) and then do the evaluation (`!!`

```
mtcars %>% 
     select(!! (rlang::sym("cyl")): !!(rlang::sym("wt")))
```

It would be when these are stored in an object

```
a <- "cyl"
b <- "wt"

mtcars %>%
  select(!! (rlang::sym(a)): !!(rlang::sym(b)))
```

Or another option is

```
mtcars %>%
    select(!! rlang::parse_expr(glue::glue("{a}:{b}")))
```

Comment: @J.Con It is converting to `symbol`.  You can either use `rlang::sym` or `as.symbol` from `base R`

Comment: This is an interesting solution, but please don't write code that looks like this... lol